# A trusted online or free app to convert Latex pdf(Thesis) to Word?

Tags: pdf, msword

I want to convert my thesis(pdf) to word, as university requires a softcopy to check plagiarism through Turnitin. I need an app or software which I can trust with my thesis.
 Note: I have already tried opening pdf directly in word. It is a mess.

Comment: Turnitin can read pdfs

Comment: Turnitin will not accept PDF image files, forms, or portfolios, files that do not contain highlightable text (e.g. a scanned file - usually an image), documents containing multiple files or files created with software other than Adobe Acrobat®.

Comment: This what they say at their official site

Comment: I use Turnitin here at my job, and several students (not too much!) submit PDFs created with LaTeX and it works ok. Obviously it will not check content *in* images, but that happens to Word files too. Anyway, if you want the conversion, my suggestion is to generate the PDF and import that in Word.

Comment: I have already tried that but that messes up all my figures and tables. My one figure is a combination of many other small figures. What about Pandoc is it safe?

Comment: Also: are you the first person in your university that has made a thesis in LaTeX? If not, how did other people handle this situation? (to be sure: did you try submitting your LaTeX pdf to Turnitin and make sure that it indeed does not work?)

Comment: I don't know about other students but the consultant department specifically asked for the word file. I cant argue with them this the way they are :(